# How to copy files except today date?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to using Ubuntu server.

How can I copy all files except today's date from a directory to s3 bucket? Again, I only want to copy files which are dated "up to yesterday".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **find** command with **exec**.

This can help you find files modified before a specific date:

```
find . ! -newermt 2018-11-01
```

The resulta is a list. If you wanna copy, then you can use this:

```
find . ! -newermt 2018-11-01 -type f -exec cp '{}' /path/to/send/ \;
```

More info about **find** command [here](https://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/)